# How to capture information on why my application is "hung"

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF monitoring application that uses a separate (internally developed) C# test 
infrastructure to execute tests and monitor and log the results.  I also uses a commercial package (InGear) to communicate to a PLC.  As a result, the application has LOTS of threads (most of which are created by the tools I am using).

Because of the nature of the environment, it would be very difficult to use a debugger in the target environment; so, we are both using [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to log diagnostics.

I use try/catch blocks in around my external calls and also have setup a unhandled exception handlers both at the WPF and AppDomain levels.

During our first long run the application appears to have become non-responsive and I got the standard "not responding" dialog.  Looking at the log it seems like everything just stopped.  Ex: I can see from the log that a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) was set to respond on the main thread in 1 sec; but, never did.

So.... My questions are:

1. How can I detect the hang or is hook into Window's detection that I am hung?  Note that I am assuming that it could be a higher priority thread that is blocking my UI tread; so, I probably can't respond to a Windows Message.
2. Once I do tap in, how do I find out what thread is the culprit.  Being able the log its call stack would be a big plus.

Comment: I believe capturing a process dump using WinDbg tool would help. I have not worked with it myself but you can probably search for the details.

Comment: On a C++ application I was working on at another company we had two threads that watched each other and did a crash dump whenever anything went wrong.  I was also looking at adding a creating a [MiniDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360(VS.85).aspx) that can be imported into WinDbg.  I might look into that here; but, I have to be able to trap the error first.  I can't be sitting around the unit for hours waiting for it to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I was unable to determine a way to detect the 'hang' before Windows does, I was able to catch the Windows timeout exception and ultimately traced the problem to unmanaged code in the Oracle .NET component.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simplistic, but what about attaching the debugger to the process, doing a 'Break All' and then inspect the stack trace of the various threads?

Comment: Because of the nature of the environment, it would be very difficult to use a debugger in the target environment.  The devices it talks to are on a private LAN accessible only to the target PC and Visual Studio is not on that PC.  I might be able to debug it remotely; but, I have never done that before so I would have to figure that out.  Also, last time it took 4 hours of running before the application hung up; so, I don't really want to tie up my PC for that long.